# why does scala generate too much class files after compilation?

Tags: scala

I am working in Scala project, and after writing and compiling Scala code, i saw couple of class files in my destination folder.
I am curious to know why does it create too much class files?
Is there any specific reason?

Comment: What is *too much files*? Do you mean *more than one class file* for each declared class?

Comment: yes, even for single class in source file. compiler creates couple of class files.

Answer (score 9):

Scala compiler is definitely creating a lot of additional modules to make it's way to jvm representation. For example in version 2.11 it creates:

1. A `.class` for each lambda expression
2. A `.class` for each `object` and `package object`
3. A `.class` for each `trait` with implemented methods
4. A `.class` for each specialization, for example in

   ```
   class Foo[@specialized(Long, Double) A, @specialized(Long, Double) B]
   ```

   it will create 3 * 3 = 9 different classes for all `(Long, Double, AnyRef)` x `(Long Double, AnyRef)` combinations.

But these problems are definitely under fix theese days.

[Scala 2.12](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0) in exchange to `jdk 8` requirement is dropping 1 and 3 overhead, because of `SAM` lambda representations and interface default methods.

[Dotty's Linker](https://d-d.me/talks/scaladays2015/#/) has autospecialization feature which will only generate needed specialization for you code and is greatly reducing troubles with 4.